# Load Router instance in Laravel to check middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-5.5

I am trying to check whether a given middleware group contains a certain middleware. I can see the information exists within **\Illuminate\Routing\Router** on the **$request->route()** var but I am unsure how to access this information as the **$request->route()->router** property is protected.

Here is my output from doing a dd within Handler.php

```
dd($request->route());
```

Highlighted is the item I am trying to access

[image]

Comment: Try with `$request->route()->getRouter()`.

Comment: I tried this already but it only has a setRouter() method unfortunately.

Comment: Seems it is under `compiled`?

Comment: Not under compiled either. I'm thinking there must be a way to independently load \Illuminate\Routing\Router rather than trying to access it via the $request var?

Comment: You can try with [`getMiddlware()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L791) Or some similar method.

Comment: Method does not exist. I also tried $request->route()->middleware() but this returns an array of applied middleware or groups, however it does not list the middleware applied within groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164346/discussion-between-tpojka-and-synkyo).